# Limiting width of a container without knowing size of content within it with only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
main {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#details {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#details span {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>My Sweet Photo</h1>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500" />
  <div id="setting" class="flex">
    <p class="comment">Ramin Beach, had a great time.</p>
    <p class="date">January 3, 2022</p>
  </div>
  <div id="details" class="flex">
    <span>f/11</span>
    <span>1/1000 s</span>
    <span>55 mm</span>
    <span>Nikon D5200</span>
    <span>AF-S DX VR Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G II</span>
    <span>ISO 200</span>
  </div>
</main>
```

I am building a personal, instagram-like photo album web site. I want to show different kinds of pictures, but crucially, they are of various sizes: landscape, portrait, or somewhere in between. Ideally I'd like to flow the content around the picture, and have descriptions and little 'tags' of information (like what camera was used to take the picture, dates, focal length, exposure time, so on) below the image.

Additionally, I'm trying to employ as little JavaScript as possible. Ideally, a purely HTML and CSS solution. I have a pretty good working layout - except on very large screens. On very large screens, the `#details` container "pushes" the width of the `<main>` container, which I don't want to do. I want to keep the entire layout's maximum width to be the natural width of the image. At the same time, I want the image to maintain its aspect ratio and always render so that it takes up 100% of the viewport (thus the specific CSS rules on the image below).

On smaller width screens, my code below works well, as the image naturally scales down in its width. On larger screens, or when the image is in a portrait orientation (height is larger than width), the details container starts taking up more and more of the width of the screen, and the layout between the image and the text below the image becomes misaligned.

I've previously solved this issue with JavaScript: when the page finishes loading, I set the max-width of the `<main>` element to be the calculated width once the image has loaded.

**The question is: is there a way to do this with only HTML and CSS?**

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question, and I changed your example image link to show a real placeholder image. Please review what I have done to make sure it properly shows what you want it to.  You can also change the numbers on the end of the image link to show the image at a different size if you need it to.

Comment: Oh crap I think I did the exact same thing at the same time you did!

Comment: Ha, no problem - same edits!  So when I view that full screen it seems to work fine. The image never gets bigger than it should and it shrinks down when I resize my window. Am I missing something?

Comment: The image sizing works great as-is with my code above. My problem is that the `#details` div with all the little extra bits of information seems to "push" the width of the `<main>` container higher. Ideally I want the text to be aligned with the edges of the image: the text should not be wider than the width of the image, but I don't know how to achieve that without JavaScript 

Comment: It sounds like what you want is media queries.

Comment: Media queries will give a jagged response.

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
  display: inline-block;
}
#container {
  width: min-content;
}
#just-image{
  min-width:200px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#details {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
#details span {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="container">
  <h1>My Sweet Photo</h1>
  <div id="just-image">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div id="setting" class="flex">
    <p class="comment">Ramin Beach, had a great time.</p>
    <p class="date">January 3, 2022</p>
  </div>
  <div id="details">
    <span>f/11</span>
    <span>1/1000 s</span>
    <span>55 mm</span>
    <span>Nikon D5200</span>
    <span>AF-S DX VR Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G II</span>
    <span>ISO 200</span>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

This is how I would do it. Add a div around the `<img>` called `#just-image`. This div would have a `min-width`. The reason for `min-width` is that I still need a way to know how the site behaves at the smallest width I allow, so that I can plan for that. After that, add a bigger div `<div id="container"`around everything. I added css for those divs. So this will work as follows: `#details` div has `width:100%` and so it will follow the width of `#container`. `#container` div has `width:min-content` and so it will have the width of the smallest element, and in this case `#just-image` div. `#just-image` has `min-width:200px` and so, for images larger than 200px it will stretch to follow the width of `<img>`. If you plan on having images smaller than 200px then you can change the `min-width` of `#just-image`.

But to have a more predictable behaviour I would advise you have some restrictions. So you will see that if the image width drops below 200px the code breaks, but that's by design. You can allow for widths smaller than 200px but you will see that the text in your `details` div will start to look funny the smaller the div. So it's better to have restrictions.

Comment: This is super close to what I'm looking for! But I see one issue in my testing: the image height gets scaled down below my ideal desired height of `100vh`. I always want the image to take up the entire height of the viewport. As these pictures are from a DSLR, they are multiple-megapixels in size, so I can expect at least 3000px in natural height, so I think most if not all screens should be able to render them at `100vh`. If I set the `height: 100vh` and `width: auto`, I lose the aspect ratio. Setting `aspect-ratio: auto` also does not seem to work.

Comment: So you want ```max-height``` of the image to be ```100vh```

Comment: Correct, which it already is set to. It seems that setting the width of the `#container` to `min-content` squeezes the image down such that its height is less than `100vh`. I tried setting `height: 100vh` on the image, but this then changes the aspect ratio.